# Get only one matching row from Solr array

Tags: solr

How do I get only a row which matches my query: ?q=taxonomy_ids:1/636/*

Got that result:

[image]

Want only: `<str>1/636/587</str>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no easy way. However, there is a trick, where you use a match highlighter and use those results instead of the results returned from the search itself. You may want to configure PRE/POST highlight tags to empty strings. There was an article on the web about somewhere, but I can't find it again.

The disadvantage is that you get your results twice. Once as docs and once as highlight.

The other option is a custom component that hooks into Lucene's explain structure.